# Palindrome substring sorter in C

Tags: c, string, palindrome

I was given an assignment to make a program that determines the number of unique palindromes that are substrings. The unique palindromes must be arranged in terms of its length and in alphabetical order. I was able to determine the substring palindromes but I can't figure out how to arrange them in alphabetical order.

I forgot to mention that we are only supposed to use stdio.h

Here is what its supposed be like when you input 'amadama':
The 6 unique palindromes in 'amadama' are 'a','d','m','ada','madam',and 'amadama'.
but my program does this:
The 12 unique palindromes in 'amadama' are 'a','m','ama','a','d','ada','madam','amadama','a','m','ama','a'.

Comment: Just a general thing about programming: Avoid functions longer than 20 lines. Smaller functions are more readable more efficient, easier to debug, and easier to write.

Answer (score 1):

Your "supposed to be like" list doesn't seem to include `ama` despite the fact it appears to meet the criteria. You should probably clarify that with the educator.

Once clarified, the next step you need to take is to remove the duplicates from your output. Your output actually seems correct but for the fact that it still has duplicated values so I'd start with what you have so far.

Given that it's classwork, I won't give you the full solution but I *will* say that one option is to sort the words (such as with `qsort`) then output them in such a way that duplicates are removed.

The following pseudo-code is one way to do that with a sorted array:

```
output word[0]
for index = 1 to word.numelements - 1:
    if word[index] != word[index - 1]:
        output word[index]
```

If you have troubles getting `qsort` to behave as you expect (and many do), another option is to simply remove the duplicates with something like:

```
for index1 = 0 to word.numelements - 2:
    for index2 = index1 + 1 to word.numelements - 1:
        if word[index1] == word[index2]:
            word[index2] = ""
```

and then output the ones that *haven't* been set to an empty string:

```
for index = 0 to word.numelements - 1:
    if word[index] != "":
        output word[index]
```

Note that I'm leaving it up to you to translate that pseudo-code into C but you should remember a couple of things:

- String comparisons should be done with `strcmp()` rather than `==` and `!=`.
- You can set strings to be empty simply by setting their first character to the NUL byte: `str[0] = '\0'`.
- You can check if a string is empty by using `strlen()` or by checking the first character is set to the NUL byte.

Comment: Yeah i clarified that already, it was supposed to be printed out as well! Thanks

Comment: How do I code it in such a way that I wont need to use the strlen() function? We are not allowed to use other libraries except stdio

Comment: @Neil, `if (strlen(s) == 0)` can be done with `if (s[0] == '\0')`. `strcmp()` is a little trickier, it's probably easier to implement your own with something like: `int mystrcmp (unsigned char *s1, unsigned char *s2) { for (;;) { if (*s1 < *s2) return -1; if (*s1 > *s2) return 1; if (*s1 == '\0') break; s1++; s2++; } return 0; }`.